# Minifabric custom hyperledger fabric network on wsl2 ubuntu 20.04 platform

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, wsl-2

I am running ubuntu 20.04 on windows 10 machine using wsl2. I am setting up a hyperledger fabric 2.2 environment using the [Minifabric tool](https://github.com/litong01/minifabric). I am specifying the structure of my custom network in the spec.yaml file in the working directory:

```
fabric:
cas:
- "ca1.university.com"
- "ca2.university1.com"
- "ca3.university2.com"
- "ca4.org.com"
- "ca5.org.com"
peers: 
- "peer1.university1.com"
- "peer2.university1.com"
- "peer3.university1.com"
- "peer4.university1.com"
- "peer5.university1.com"
- "peer6.university1.com"
- "peer7.university1.com"
- "peer8.university1.com"
- "peer9.university1.com"
- "peer1.university2.com"
- "peer2.university2.com"
- "peer3.university2.com"
- "peer4.university2.com"
- "peer5.university2.com"
- "peer6.university2.com"
- "peer7.university2.com"
- "peer8.university2.com"
- "peer1.organization_x.com"
- "peer2.organization_x.com"
- "peer3.organization_x.com"
- "peer1.organization_y.com"
- "peer2.organization_y.com"
- "peer3.organization_y.com"
- "peer1.organization_z.com"
- "peer2.organization_z.com"
- "peer3.organization_z.com"
orderers:
- "orderer1.university1.com"
- "orderer2.university1.com"
- "orderer3.university1.com"
- "orderer1.university2.com"
- "orderer2.university2.com"
- "orderer3.university2.com"
- "orderer1.organization_x.com"
- "orderer1.organization_y.com"
- "orderer1.organization_z.com"
settings:
  ca:
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC: DEBUG
  peer:
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC: DEBUG
  orderer:
    FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC: DEBUG
```

I gave the command specifying the default organization "./minifab up -o university1.com" and got the following error:
[image]
Can someone explain why I am getting this error? TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be an artifact of copying and pasting, but the syntax of the lists in your config file don't look right...
I recommend letting yamllint run over it and taking its advice.